# How to investigate StackOverflow error in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running a cluster of 15 n1-standard-v4 workers on Dataproc. My I/O data is in Avro format.

Last stage in the spark job is to save data, which finishes with StackOverflowError.
The DAG is:

[image]

And worker statistics:

[image]

The log with the error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3076)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1618)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2093)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1655)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
```

I tried to:

1. investigate VM instance monitoring of failed workers (everything's ok)
2. balance partition size (reducing it gives the same stackoverflow error)
3. tune spark.executor.memoryOverhead, spark.serializer, etc. parameters

Nothing seems to work so far. The questions I want to ask are the following:

1. why log with error points at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readByte as the cause of the error?
2. how can I improve the investigation policy for such issues like StackOverflow?

Thanks!

Comment: @kirill_zaitsev Have you tried increasing stack size? Some deeply nested avro structures can cause the default (1MB) to be not sufficient.

Comment: @mazaneicha, thanks for the hint, it worked - stackoverflow is now not the problem. 
Save stage is enormously slow (30Gb - 1h8m) . But I guess that's a topic for another question

Comment: We'll need to see how you're saving (code sample). The final "Sort" seems especially peculiar. Apart from that, maybe its time to give up python if you want to get best performance from Spark?

Comment: @mazaneicha, just posted the issue about long write https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65349126/unusually-slow-data-write-to-cloud-storage, would be great if you could have a look.
You are perfectly right about python, the more I dive deep into spark - the less seductiive python gets