# Spark: unusually slow data write to Cloud Storage

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-storage, avro

As the final stage of the pyspark job, I need to save 33Gb of data to Cloud Storage.

My cluster is on Dataproc and consists of 15 n1-standard-v4 workers. I'm working with avro and the code I use to save the data:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, avro_schema_str)
df \
   .write \
   .format("avro") \
   .partitionBy('<field_with_<5_unique_values>', 'field_with_lots_of_unique_values>') \
   .save(f"gs://{output_path}")
```

The write stage stats from the UI:
[image]

[image]

[image]

My worker stats:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Quite strangely for the adequate partition size, the shuffle spill is huge:

[image]

The questions I want to ask are the following:

1. if the stage takes 1.3h and workers do their work for 25 mins - does it imply that driver does the 50-min write to GCS?
2. What causes a shuffle spill of this size given that no caching, persisting was used?
3. Why does the stage take so long?

**UPDATE:**

The SQL tab:

[image]

Comment: Does it also take 1.3h if you remove the `partitionBy`?

Comment: It runs for 1.2h without partitionBy

Comment: I can see 1.2h in the SQL UI tab for the single completed query

Comment: does you pyspark job only read then write data with no other transformation applied in between ?

Comment: I attached the DAG of the stage in the question. There are no actions between read and write, if you meant to ask that